# Keystonejs install fails due to lodash@3.3.1 dependency issue

Tags: node.js, lodash, keystonejs, yo

I am attempting to install Keystonejs following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@shivendraodean/keystonejs-a-javascript-cms-part-1-getting-started-ac0a754a5693), but I am receiving a dependency error message when installing yo:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for lodash@3.3.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

SPECS:
node v8.9.4
OS: macOS HighSierra V10.13.3

It appears that lodash@3.3.1 had an issue with the NPM register at the time, but this makes me wonder why this hasn't be upgraded within yo - which in turn makes me thing I am somehow screwing up the process.

Anyway anyone could point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: which dependancies are you using ? From what I saw, yo and Keystonejs use Lodash v4 ... . The only possible problem I thought could be the not upgraded package-lock of these project (one of yo dependancies uses lodash v3) ?

Comment: This happens simply when I enter 'npm install -g yo' seems like its not accurately maintained in npm?

Comment: I didn't found anything close to your problem in their issue tracker : https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues . Maybe a node issue with your mac ? (Try to use node 8.10 : who knows -  https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V8.md#8.10.0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **don't have** the answer, but I just thought I'd share with you:

My `node` is `v7.10.1` and my  `npm` is `4.2.0` and I can install lodash@**3.3.1** without any problem:

```
me@computer:~/Downloads/lodash-test$ npm install lodash@3.3.1
/home/me/Downloads/lodash-test
└── lodash@3.3.1
```

---

Also I can install `yo` without any issue, and the its `lodash` dependencies have version `4.17.5`:

```
me@computer:~/Downloads/lodash-test$ npm install yo
...
...
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version

Everything looks all right!
/home/me/Downloads/lodash-test
└─┬ yo@2.0.1 
  ├─┬ async@2.6.0 
  │ └── lodash@4.17.5 
...
...
  ├── lodash@4.17.5 
  ├─┬ meow@3.7.0 
  │ ├─┬ camelcase-keys@2.1.0 
...
...
```

---

I developed a web page with KeystoneJS a few months ago around December 2017. When I look at its `package.json` file, I see that the `lodash` version is `4.13.1`:

```
    ...
    "keystone": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    ...
```